# Mysql - Summary Report - Remove Duplicates - Total Sum of Column

Tags: mysql

I have a table keeping tract of devices, and their relationships in Mysql.

A single device can be related to multiple objects.  I would like unique the deviceId so I'm not counting the device multiple times, and provide the grand total of the capacity of all devices.

```
Array | Capacity | deviceId | Assignment
 4321    1024       3eb        esx1
 4321    1024       3eb        esx2
 4321    1024       3eb        esx3
 4321    28672      3ec        win1
 4321    61440      9f1        unassigned
```

I want a report similar to the following

```
Array | Capacity 
 4321    91136
```

I've tried `select sum(Capacity) from table group by deviceId` and this doesn't give me the expected results.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This kind of problem can be symptomatic of poor (i.e. non-normalised) design. Can the same deviceid simultaneously hold different capacities?

Comment: always the same capacity for the deviceid, just multiple assigments

Comment: So capacity should be in a separate table.

Answer (score 0):

Assumes duplicate data (first 3 columns) as shown in Question:

```
create table table1
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    Array int not null,
    Capacity int not null,
    deviceId varchar(100) not null,
    Assignment varchar(100) not null
);
truncate table table1;
insert table1(array,capacity,deviceId,assignment) values 
(4321,1024,'3eb','blah'),
(4321,1024,'3eb','blah'),
(4321,1024,'3eb','blah'),
(4321,28672,'3ec','blah'),
(4321,61440,'9f1','blah');

select Array,sum(Capacity) as Capacity 
from 
( select distinct Array,Capacity,deviceId
  from table1
) xxx 
group by Array;

+-------+----------+
| Array | Capacity |
+-------+----------+
|  4321 |    91136 |
+-------+----------+
```

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you

Comment: My sad lonely answer forsaken by the world.